# Microsoft Bot Framework's verifyBotFramework() always returning Forbidden

Tags: node.js, frameworks, bots, botframework

I'm trying to create a bot using new Microsoft's Bot Framework and Node.JS.

The problem is that, even thought I give the verifyBotFramework() method the right AppId and App Secret, I keep getting forbidden.

The bot works just fine in the emulator, but when I try to reach it through Telegram, it says "Forbidden".

Also, I can't use the "Test connection to your bot", since it doesn't even return an error message.

Here goes my code:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var server = restify.createServer();

//Criando bot e adicionando diálogos
var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot();
bot.add('/', new builder.CommandDialog()
    .matches('^set name', builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('/profile'))
    .matches('^quit', builder.DialogAction.endDialog())
    .onDefault(function(session) {
        if (!session.userData.name) {
            session.beginDialog('/profile');
        } else {
            session.send('Hello, %s!', session.userData.name);
        }
    })
);


bot.add('/profile', [
    function(session) {
        if (session.userData.name) {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What would you like me to call you instead?');
        } else {
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hey there =). What\'s your name?');
        }
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);

//Configurando Restify
server.use(bot.verifyBotFramework({ appId: 'myappid', appSecret: 'myappsecret' }));
server.post('/v1/messages', bot.listen());
server.listen(process.env.port || 3978, function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

And no, I'm not using "myappsecret" and "myappid", I just replaced them here.

PS: I'm using the App Secret generated by the framework control panel. I tried both the primary and secondary App Secrets.

Comment: Setting up HTTPS with Let's Encrypt certificate and Key solved the issue.

Comment: Notice that since Bot Framework SDK version 3+, you no longer need to call `verifyBotFramework`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using HTTPS. If you are using HTTP you need to disable basic auth because BotFramework won't send your appSecret in the clear.

Comment: Thanks! And can the certificate be a self signed one?

Comment: No, it must be a properly chained cert that's valid for your hostname, sorry.

Comment: No problem, got a Let's Encrypt cert and it worked perfectly =)

Comment: I don't get it. SSL is only on port 443, isn't it? How can I get it to work with the framework's 3978?